# How should I deal with this conditional promise in a return statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to perform several functions, some of which **may** include asynchronous callbacks (based on conditions) when a button is clicked.

I have a submit button that *I do not* want to prevent default behavior on to perform these operations (i.e. e.preventDefault())

Instead, I need to simply return true or false:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(e) {
    return mdl.entry(e);
});

var mdl: {
  entry: function(evt) {
    if (condition) {
      return ...
    } else {
      return anotherFunction();
    }
  }
}

function anotherFunction() {
  // This function could potentially involve one or more 
  // asynchronous requests
  some.func(obj).then(function(result) {
    ... do stuff
  });
}
```

What's the best way to deal with this? I know I can poll a global variable, or set a variable and trigger a click event:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(e) {
    if (!safeToSubmit) {
      e.preventDefault();
      mdl.entry(e); 
      // when finished, it sets safeToSubmit to true
      // and triggers a click on the button 
    } 
});
```

I hope my issue makes sense. Above is dummy code. Probably 10 different functions that conditionally make asynchronous calls. Perhaps a best practices question? I can make it work... I just want a better way :)

Comment: You *cannot* synchronously return. You have to always return `false`, and then when all actions are finished (and have `true` as their result), submit the form directly.

Comment: @Bergi I was afraid of that. At least I haven't been doing it wrong all this time.

Comment: Why are you attempting to `return` from within an event handler?

Comment: @guest271314 Same reason you would use preventDefault, except not destroying the execution chain.

Comment: It may not be possible to dispatch an event at an element within or following asynchronous procedures. What exactly is issue and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is `"#submitBtn"` an `<input type="submit">` or an `<input type="file">` element?

Comment: @guest271314 I've done it plenty, in success callbacks and other methods. I want to (as clean as possible) make the return value wait on whatever result may come its way, whether that result is synchronous or asynchronous, and by nature this can't happen, but time has proven people have come up with creative ways to deal with things.

Comment: That still does not answer the question of what exactly you are trying to achieve? You can use `Promise.resolve(condition).then(trueOrFalse => if (trueOrFalse) // do stuff else return stuff // do other stuff return stuff)`. However, that functionality will not allow you to trigger `click` at an `<input type="file">` element within the asynchronous code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150036/discussion-between-user1447679-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to always return a Promise. For synchronous functions instead of `return someValue` you `return Promise.resolve(someValue)`

Then you can deal with the return value the same way for everything with something like:

```
mdl.entry(e)
.then((ret) => { //do stuff with ret })
```

EDIT:

I am imagining something like this:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(e) {
    mdl.entry(e)
    .then((ret) => { /* whatever is supposed to be donw with the return */ })
});

var mdl = {
entry: function(evt) {
    if (condition) {
        var res = someSynchronousFunction(evy)
        return Promise.resolve(res)
    } else {
        return anotherFunction();
    }
}
}

function anotherFunction() {
    return someAsyncFunction(obj).then(function(result) {  
    //... do stuff and return a value
    // someAsyncFunction will return a promise that resolves to this value
    });
}
```

Comment: Would you mind taking some more snippets from my code to elaborate a little more? Please :)

Comment: @user1447679 Sure, maybe the edit will make it a little clearer. You might want to put different things in different places, but the basic idea is that you don't want to mix async and sync code. You want it to all be async, which `Promise.resolve()` allows you to do.